# How do I automate a subtraction of columns in R?

Tags: r

What I want to do is to automate a subtraction of different columns and divide if possible. My data looks like this:

```
 colnames <- c("HFW01_V2", "HFW01_V2", "HFW01_V3", "HFW02_V2" ,"HFW02_V3", "HFW03_V2", "HFW03_V3")
df <- tibble( Sample = c("s001", "s002", "s003", "s004", "s005", "s006"),
   HFW01_V2 = 5:8,
   HFW01_V3 = 10:13,
   HFW02_V2 = 15:18,
   HFW02_V3 = 20:23,
   HFW03_V2 = 25:28, 
   HFW03_V3 = 28:31)
```

What I wanna do is to create new columns that have the result of (HFW01_V3 - HFW01_V2)/HFW01_V2 another columns with (HFW02_V3 - HFW02_V2)/HFW01_V2 and on on... because the are 38 samples it's possible to autmomate that??

Thank you <3

Comment: Welcome to SO . . . your sample data doesn't work because the columns have differing lengths.

Comment: It can be difficult enough to answer some questions, and definitely frustrating when it is clear that the asker has never used the code/data presented in the question. It is usually good-practice to reduce the data, perhaps even simplify it a little, so that the question is more bite-size, but it is also critical that the data/code be _representative_: no unrelated parsing/syntax errors, produce the same problems, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry. Because my original data was so big that I tried to make a example

Comment: Are you sure to divide always by `HFW01_V2`?

Comment: No,  jesus I did wrong again. It's to divide by the V2 of the correspondent sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one try, pivoting, subtracting/dividing, then pivoting back to wide:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Sample, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("hfw", ".value")) %>%
  mutate(diff = (V3 - V2)/V2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Sample, names_from = "hfw", values_from = c("V2", "V3", "diff"), names_glue = "{hfw}_{.value}")
# # A tibble: 4 × 10
#   Sample HFW01_V2 HFW02_V2 HFW03_V2 HFW01_V3 HFW02_V3 HFW03_V3 HFW01_diff HFW02_diff HFW03_diff
#   <chr>     <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 s001          5       15       25       10       20       25      1          0.333          0
# 2 s002          6       16       26       11       21       26      0.833      0.312          0
# 3 s003          7       17       27       12       22       27      0.714      0.294          0
# 4 s004          8       18       28       13       23       28      0.625      0.278          0
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Sample = c("s001", "s002", "s003", "s004"), HFW01_V2 = 5:8, HFW01_V3 = 10:13, HFW02_V2 = 15:18, HFW02_V3 = 20:23, HFW03_V2 = 25:28, HFW03_V3 = 25:28), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that took me a while and I am not satisfied to 100%. I somehow can't combine line 2 and 3:

Credits @r2evans whose solution helped a lot to find my answer!

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_V3'), ~ . - get(str_replace(cur_column(), "V3$", "V2")))) %>% 
  transmute(across(ends_with('_V3'), ~ . / get(str_replace(cur_column(), "V3$", "V2")), .names = "diff_{.col}")) %>% 
  bind_cols(df)
```

```
 diff_HFW01_V3 diff_HFW02_V3 diff_HFW03_V3 Sample HFW01_V2 HFW01_V3 HFW02_V2 HFW02_V3 HFW03_V2 HFW03_V3
          <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>     <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1         1             0.333         0.2   s001          5       10       15       20       25       30
2         0.833         0.312         0.192 s002          6       11       16       21       26       31
3         0.714         0.294         0.185 s003          7       12       17       22       27       32
4         0.625         0.278         0.179 s004          8       13       18       23       28       33
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help!! I will try yours as well <333